# Grouping by one column in hive, want to select any entry from another coloumn

Tags: hive

So I have a hive table with the following two columns:

```
TABLE: t, 
Columns: url string, json string
```

In the table there might be multiple entries for the same url. I want to choose only one json per url. 
However, I couldn't find a suitable agrregator function to choose one among the jsons.

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT url, Aggregator(json) 
FROM t 
GROUP BY url;
```

Any suggestions for a suitable aggregator function that allows me to select one element from a set?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned how you want to choose the 'json' value, I take it that it doesn't matter. There are two ways to do this.

**Sample data**

```
select url, json from t order by url, json;

234 Test_2
234 Test_3
234 Test_1
123 Test_3
123 Test_2
123 Test_1
```

Use the `first_value` function.

```
select url, val from 
(select url, first_value(json) val from t) a 
group by url, val;

234 Test_2
123 Test_2
```

Another approach is to make use of the `Chooseone` UDF from Facebook (https://github.com/brndnmtthws/facebook-hive-udfs/blob/master/src/main/java/com/facebook/hive/udf/UDAFChooseOne.java)

```
create temporary function choose_one as 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDAFChooseOne';

select url, choose_one(json) from t group by url;

123 Test_3
234 Test_2
```